# Retry an update in bigquery does not seem to work

Tags: python, google-bigquery

When i run the following code :

```
bq_client = google.cloud.bigquery.Client(project='project')
query1 = """
UPDATE dataset.table SET col = 1 where id = 'a' 
"""
query2 = """
UPDATE dataset.table SET col = 2 where id = 'b' 
"""
p = google.api_core.retry.if_exception_type(Exception)
r = google.api_core.retry.Retry(predicate=p)
bq_client.query(query1)
bq_client.query(query2, retry=r)
```

the first query job succeeds but the second query job fails (because bigquery does not support simultaneous updates) and seems to be never retried. However, i pass a "Retry" object which catches all exceptions to my second query job. I do not understand why this second query job is not retried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is that the retry option retries the API call to insert the job, but it doesn't actually retry the job for you.

In this case the API "succeeds" (at least as far as HTTP error codes are concerned), but the response body says the job failed.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, if I turn off Internet, the retry works !

Comment: On another note, if i delete a table which does not exist, the retry works (even with the internet on). It is because the method delete ensure that the table does not exist anymore. Am i right ?

Comment: Delete retries because delete is not considered a "job" (long-running operation). So if the delete fails, the API does return an error status.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround in python:

```
max_tries = 7
def myJob():
   for n in range(max_tries):
       try:
           myQueryJob()
           break
       except Exception:
           if n == max_tries - 1:
               raise Exception
           time.sleep(2**n)
```

It will try you QueryJob up to 7 times with a kind of exponential backoff.

Comment: does this need a `break` after `myQueryJob()` in the `try` to avoid looping if successful?

Comment: You're right! @mrlevitas